# How to Marshal a System.IO.Stream to C++

Tags: casting, clr, marshalling, managed-c++

I am looking for a solution to pass a System.IO.Stream back and forth between a C# service and a C++ client, for this I want to use C++/CLI.

I already tried casting to a System.String, but I believe that is not the best way to do this.

Comment: How are you defining client and service here? `Stream` is an abstract base class but most, if not all, implementations are for something that's meant to be consumed within a single process, whereas most uses of the words client and service will involve some kind of multiple process (and possibly multiple machine) setup.

Comment: I use a WCF service to access the C# code, there are several clients using the same process/service. The type of the stream is not obvious for me (I know that it is an abstract base class), that is why I do not want to cast it to a System.String.